# How to map Grails domain class properties to non-matching json string?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Is there a built-in / easy way to set mappings between domain class properties and JSON strings that don't have exact matches for the property names?

For example, when I have a domain class:

```
class Person {
    String jobTitle
    String favoriteColor
    static constraints = {
        jobTitle(blank: false)
        favoriteColor(blank: false)
    }
}
```

And someone's giving me the following JSON:

```
{ "currentJob" : "secret agent", "the-color" : "red" }
```

I'd like to be able to still do this:

```
new Person(request.JSON).save()
```

Is there a way in groovy/grails for me to map currentJob -> jobTitle and the-color -> favorite color?

**EDIT:**

I've done a little experimenting, but I still haven't gotten it working. But I have found out a couple interesting things...

At first I tried overwriting the setProperty method:

```
@Override
setProperty(String name, Object value) {
    if(this.hasProperty(name)) this[name] = value
    else {
        switch(name) {
            'currentJob': this.jobTitle = value; break;
            'the-color': this.favoriteColor = value; break;
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work for two reasons: 1) setProperty is only called if there is a property that matches name and 2) "this[name] = value" calls setProperty, leading to an infinite recursive loop.

So then I thought, well screw it, I know what the incoming json string looks like (If only I could control it), I'll just get rid of the line that handles the scenario where the names match and I'll override hasProperty, maybe that will work:

```
@Override
void setProperty(String name, Object value) {
    switch(name) {
        'currentJob': this.jobTitle = value; break;
        'the-color': this.favoriteColor = value; break;
    }
}
@Override
boolean hasProperty(String name) {
    if(name == "currentJob" || name == "the-color") return true
    return false
}
```

But no, that didn't work either. By a random stroke of luck I discovered, that not only did I have to overwrite hasProperty(), but I also had to have an empty setter for the property.

```
void setCurrentJob(){ }
```

That hack worked for currentJob - I guess setProperty only gets called if hasProperty returns true and there is a setter for the property (Even if that setter is auto generated under the covers in grails). Unfortunately I can't make a function "setThe-Color" because of the dash, so this solution doesn't work for me.

Still stuck on this, any help would definitely be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Overriding the void propertyMissing(String name, Object value){} method is called by this:

```
Person person = new Person()
person["currentJob"] = "programmer"
person["the-color"] = "red"
```

But not by this:

```
Person person = new Person(["currentJob":"programmer", "the-color":"red"])
```

Comment: There is a way to do this with Grails 2.4.  Are you using 2.4?

Comment: Ahhh, no, I'm using 2.3.4 :(

Comment: How would you do it in 2.4, just out of curiosity?

Comment: In 2.4 you can register your own `DataBindingSourceCreator` and do a lot of interesting things there, including mapping property names like you are wanting to do.  We need to improve the docs around some of this as there are capabilities like this that haven't been documented.

Comment: For 2.3.4, what's the easiest way accomplish this? I've been trying to overwrite the domain class's constructor (the one that takes a map parameter), but this is proving frustratingly difficult. The new constructor I create is never used, as apparently the meta class's constructor is called instead.